# Change AngularJs localization

Tags: angularjs, localization

I'm trying to change Angular localization in "ng-click" to achieve multi language in my application.
To do this I'm changing script source, but it isn't return expected result

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $locale) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.currentLang =$locale.id;
  $scope.changeLanguage= function(langKey){
    document.getElementById("langSrc").src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/i18n/angular-locale_"+langKey+".js";
    $scope.currentLang=langKey;
  }
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a ng-show="currentLang!='en-us'" ng-click="changeLanguage('en-us')">English</a>
  <a ng-show="currentLang!='hy-am'" ng-click="changeLanguage('hy-am')">Հայերեն</a>


  <h2>{{currentLang}} : {{date | date}}  </h2>
</body>
```

Does anyone have a some idea?
[Plunker example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7i6Ot7UXu6e0FlzT3z7C?p=preview)

Comment: is plunker is correct? its not showing your code

Comment: try this [embed plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/7i6Ot7UXu6e0FlzT3z7C/preview)